# Which test case am i missing?

Tags: c, algorithm, testing

I was solving a question. But I am missing something. There's some test case for which my solution is wrong. I need to find that test case.
For the other subtask, it is saying that execution took too long.

> Chef will have access to Discourse if his knowledge and power become exactly equal to N and M respectively. Initially, he has power
>   1 and knowledge 1.
>
> Chef can perform actions of the following types to improve his skills:
>
> - solve a problem — increase his knowledge by X
> - do a push-up — increase his power by Y
> - install ShareChat to keep in touch with friends — increase both knowledge and power by 1
>
> Chef can only install ShareChat at most once. The remaining actions may be performed any number of times and the actions may be
>   performed in any order.
>
> Help Chef find out whether it is possible to move from Discuss to Discourse.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
>
> The first and only line of each test case contains four space-separated integers N, M, X and Y.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, print a single line containing the string "Chefirnemo" if it is possible to reach the required knowledge and
>   power or "Pofik" if it is impossible

you can also visit this link to read the question
Link to question https://www.codechef.com/SEPT18B/problems/CHEFADV
My solution-

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
            long int n,m,x,y,power,know;
            scanf("%ld%ld%ld%ld",&n,&m,&x,&y);
            power=1;
            know=1;
            if(power+1==m && know+1==n)
                printf("Chefirnemo\n");
            else {
                while(power+y<m)
                    power=power+y;
                if(power+y==m)
                    power=power+y;
                while(know+x<n)
                    know=know+x;
                if(know+x==n)
                    know=know+x;
                if(power==m && know==n)
                    printf("Chefirnemo\n");
                else if(power+1==m && know+1==n)
                    printf("Chefirnemo\n");
                else
                    printf("Pofik\n");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please give complete information of the required help in the question instead of sharing links. it will help people to help you.

Comment: TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED

Comment: read about the modulo operation (`%`) It should help with the TLE problem

Comment: Yeah but TLE isn't the bigger issue. The bigger issue is the error which i am unable to spot. KIndly help me with that

Comment: You tagged this `C++`, but it looks like `C` to me.  I don't see any C++ usage.

Comment: @ Walter i didn't get u. Can u please elaborate[ (power-1)/m and (know-1)/n are either both 0 or 1.]  this part. Thanks for your help

Comment: @abelenky: It's perfectly valid (if buggy) C++.

Comment: @abelenky The C++ tag was not added by OP.

Comment: Wonder if problems from active contest are off-topic here?!

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails if either `x==1` and `(m-1)%y==1` or vice versa (i.e. `y==1` and `(n-1)%x==1`). Then your iteration will increase `power` to `n` and `know` to `m-1` when installing ShareChat cannot help. However, had you increased `power` only to `n-1`, installing ShareChat would have obtained a match.

A correct solution should treat the installation of ShareChat more careful. For example

```
bool chefirnemo(int n, int m, int x, int y)
{
    // 0 check that input is okay
    assert(1<=n && 1<=m && 1<=x && 1<=y);
    // 1 change to the equivalent problem where power
    //   and knowledge are 0 initially
    --n; --m;
    // 2 try w/o installation of ShareChat:
    if (n>=0 && (n%x)==0 && m>=0 && (m%y)==0)
        return true;
    // 3 install ShareChat
    --n; --m;
    // 4 try again
    return (n>=0 && (n%x)==0 && m>=0 && (m%y)==0);
}
```

Comment: Btw, this website lives from people being grateful, which is reflected by accepting an answer and/or up-voting an answer or a question.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new. Can you reply to my previous comment please?

Comment: Even your answer isn't correct my friend. I tried out with some test cases,it's not giving the desired answer. for eg- 2 2 1 2 it should be true. But your solution is giving it as false. And your loop becomes infinite in test cases like 5 2 3 0

Comment: I thought 1≤N,M,X,Y≤109, so 5,2,3,0 is not allowed. And I fixed the other issue (btw, my code has no loop, so it's not clear what you meant).

Comment: I don't know about the author of this question but your code works perfectly, here's a +10 from my side

Comment: @Divik it's because I fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your rules don't guarantee that the inputs are positive.  If X or Y is zero, your loops never terminate.  (Note, this is a problem with your paraphrase, the challenge rules do assure positive values)

   Test case: 2 2 0 0

   Test case: 2 4 0 2

   Test case: 4 4 1 0
2. How many times you apply (+X,0) and (0,+Y) should depend on whether the (+1,+1) action is used... but you have already locked in your decision.

   Test case: 5 6 1 2

Comment: The problem has following constraints: Constraints
1≤T≤1,000
1≤N,M,X,Y≤109

Comment: @Slycoder: The problem does.  Your question doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! I find it difficult Identifying such test cases where my solution fails. Can you please tell me how it's done? how did you find out ?

Answer (score -1):

although Walter does point out the possible hints.
the solution does not seem to be working.

Comment: Yes absolutely. His code couldn't't overcome the shortcomings my code had. It has the same problens

Comment: This should just be a comment